# Controller & View Code for Trivia Game

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to Ruby 1.9.3 on Rails 3.2 and working on personal project to learn. It's a pretty basic multiple choice trivia game and I'm having trouble with writing the code in the Controllers and Views to enable a user to click on a "play" link that will randomly show a question and the question_choices. The user should then select one of four radio button corresponding to one of the four question_choices. The question, and question_choice gets added to the user_answers table then the next question is displayed. Also, I don't want the users to see the same questions twice.

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :questions
  has_many :question_choices
  has_many :user_answers, dependent: :destroy
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :level, :question, :is_active

    has_many :user_answers, through: :question_choices
    has_many :question_choices, dependent: :destroy
end

class QuestionChoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :choice, :is_correct, :question_id

  has_many :user_answers, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :question
end

class UserAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :answer_time, :user_id, :question_choice_id, :question_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :question_choice
end
```

My Routes:

```
Trivia::Application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]  

  resources :questions do
    resources :question_choices
  end

  resources :users
  resources :user_answers
end
```

I've been able to use the scaffolding for 'index', 'new', 'edit' & 'show' for each separately but I'm having a tough time tying it together so the User can see a question and the question choices then select one and their UserAnswers gets updated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.
Shane

Comment: Your question is vague. If you're just starting out with rails, I would recommend working through the [rails tutorail](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your data model is a bit complicated. Let's look at the requirements

We have three objects: Users, Questions, and answers (QuestionChoices).
We know some things about the relationship between these objects:

1. A question has multiple answers
2. A user is going to answer multiple questions
3. A question is going to be answered by multiple users
4. A user should only answer a question once

Number 1 is a simple relationship with a question having many question choices:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :level, :question, :is_active
  has_many :question_choices, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Number 2 relates to the user model and that's pretty simple:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :user_answers, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Okay, now for UserAnswers. It's job is to connect a question choice with a user:

```
class UserAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :answer_time, :user_id, :question_choice_id, question_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :question_choice

  validates :question_id, uniqueness: { :scope => :user_id }

end
```

That validation is the answer to number 4. It says "If you group all of the user answers together based on their user, each question should only appear once." So if a user tries to answer a question twice, it will reject the creation of this item in the DB.

Number three isn't really a requirement, but something you need to make sure your data models controls for. We have nothing that would prevent this.

Comment: Hi Chris! Thank you for your answer. What about the QuestionChoices? And how do I show the question with the question choices to the user?